# Kivy: Incorrectly displayed characters

Tags: python, kivy

Here is a simple code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label

class TutorialApp(App):
    def build(self):
        l = Label(text='[sɪɡˈnɪfɪk(ə)ns]')
        return l
if __name__ == "__main__":
    TutorialApp().run()
```

I get the following result: [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cfR35.png)

Incorrectly displayed some characters

How to fix it?

Comment: put a `u` in front of the string to make it a Unicode object. `u'[sɪɡˈnɪfɪk(ə)ns]'` You also need to ensure that your output device (sys.stdout) has a utf-8 (rather than ascii) codec attached; and finally you need to ensure you have a font that includes the glyphs referenced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that your font doesn't contain these characters. That's why it shows only rectangles instead.

Try using a [different font](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.font_name).